# Change Date format in Magento recent order view

Tags: php, date, magento-1.7

In customer's account page the date of order placed is shown as **1/17/13** but i want to display it as **2013/01/17**. How can I change the format of the date?

Comment: Try: this System > Catalog > Date & Time Custom Options

Comment: Thanks. That allowed me to change the order of the year, day and month. But How can change the format of the year, i.e. display it in 4 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: this System > Catalog > Date & Time Custom Options;

and at date function specify 'Y' for getting 4 digit letter